# How to send multidimensional array from php to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to get this "data" multidimensional array value in my javascript function. How can I get it?

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/tanzilamohita/7nhv5h8h/

```
function getJSarray(){
var data = new Array;
data = document.getElementsByName("data[]");
alert(data.length);
//alert(hidden_courses[2].value);
}
```

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply by using [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `$('[name^="data["]')` in jquery

```js
function getJSarray() {
  var data = new Array;
  data = $('[name^="data["]');
  alert(data.length);
  console.log('Alternatively use querySelectorAll '+document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='data[']").length);
  return false;
  //alert(hidden_courses[2].value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return getJSarray()">
  A1<input type="radio" name="data[0][]" value="1" /><br /> A2
  <input type="radio" name="data[0][]" value="2" /><br /> B1
  <input type="radio" name="data[1][]" value="3" /><br /> B2
  <input type="radio" name="data[1][]" value="4" /><br />
  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**Alternatively,** use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like, `document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='data[']")`;

To get the checked elements use [:checked-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector) like

```js
function getJSarray() {
  var data = new Array;
  data = $('[name^="data["]:checked');
  alert(data.length);
  return false;
  //alert(hidden_courses[2].value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" onsubmit="return getJSarray()">
  A1<input type="radio" name="data[0][]" value="1" /><br /> A2
  <input type="radio" name="data[0][]" value="2" /><br /> B1
  <input type="radio" name="data[1][]" value="3" /><br /> B2
  <input type="radio" name="data[1][]" value="4" /><br />
  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks.
How can I get an alert only for the selected values?

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Comment: It shows the length of the selected values. But How can I get the values. Suppose, If I select A2 and B1, alert will be 2, 3.

Comment: @TanzilaIslam  to get checked values https://jsfiddle.net/7nhv5h8h/1/

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `$('[name^="data["]:checked').map(function(){return this.value;}).get()`